# Is it possible to reset my adsense balance?

Tags: google-adsense

There is not really much to add to the title for some private reason i need to reset my balance in adsense (which is very small)

Note that I haven't activated the pin code yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily reset your balance. Once you reach your payment threshold, the payout will occur and your balance reset then.